# Using devise with a slightly different registration flow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

Before devise, I had a model called Participant which contained info for users. It had a controller and set of views to go with it. I added devise, and asked that it used Participant for the user records. That seemed to work just fine.

Now in my world,  the route to create a participant looked like this: ./program/2/participant/new because any participant other than the singular "administrator" is created and used always within a single program. The participant model already has a belongs_to :program.

My Routes look like this:

```
  devise_for :participants

  root to: 'programs#index'
  resources :programs do
    resources :participants do
      resources :rounds do
        get 'survey' => 'rounds#present_survey'
        put 'survey' => 'rounds#store_survey'
      end
    end
    resources :questions
    resources :rounds
    member do
      get 'report' => 'reports#report'
    end
  end
```

I am a little confused about the structure of things. When I bring all the views from devises engine into my app, I get views/devise/registrations/edit and new. I want them to be /view/participants/edit and new.

And I want the routes and all that to behave accordingly. When I create a new Participant, I will know from the route what Program it is in, and be able to set up the program_id correctly. When the user logs in, unless they are "admin" I want them to be redirected to the route like ./program/3.

I am not sure how to approach this. Can you give me some tips, that would be appreciated!!

-- Pito

Answer (score 1):

you have to do something as follow

```
class ParticipantsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    ... # your code of new
  end

  def update
    ... # your code of update
  end
end
```

and in routes

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "participants" }
```

hope it would help

Comment: That's a great tip. What about the route though... I need the route to look like ./program/3/participant/sign_up etc. I have edited my original question to show what routes look like now.

Comment: i would suggest you to have a look at devise routing, https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

you can define your own routes using devise